# Unable to delete anything VBS related

Tags: windows, vbscript

I've been cleaning out my PC lately, and I noticed an odd problem I've never been faced with before. I cannot delete `.vbs` scripts. Not only that, but I can't delete anything that has ".VBS" at the end of it's title. Files, folders, shortcuts, you name it. If it has the extension, I get an error saying I need permission from ***myself*** to delete these files. I even made some dummy files and slapped the vbs extension on them like text documents and shortcuts and I get the same error. I even used Unlocker to remove them and it won't work either. I have attempted to take ownership of the files, but I am unable to for any of the vbs files. Any help is ***greatly*** appreciated.

Comment: Take ownership of the files ... http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't do that either...

Comment: Are you an admin ?

Comment: Yes. I am also the original owner of the PC and it's contents. This is why I find this to be so strange.

Answer (score 0):

.vbs files may be locked by Anti-Virus software or other security software. Check into that.